# How can I convert a vector into a vector with every x elements grouped into a tuple? E.g. Vec<u8> -> Vec<(u8, u8, u8)>

Tags: rust

I am trying to convert a Vec<u8> into a Vec<(u8, u8, u8)> grouping adjacent elements and want to know if there is a quick way of doing this as iteration for a large image could be quite slow.

My current best solution is:

```
let dimensions = (img.dimensions().0 as usize, img.dimensions().1 as usize);
let size = dimensions.0 * dimensions.1;
let raw_data: Vec<u8> = img.into_raw();
let mut data: Vec<(u8, u8, u8)> = Vec::with_capacity(size);

for i in 0..size {
    data.push((raw_data[i*3], raw_data[i*3+1], raw_data[i*3+2]));
}
```

Comment: Can you reuse the same `Vec`?

Comment: If not, can you live with a result of slice and not `Vec`?

Comment: That example does not push new elements to the vector, so it will always panic.

Comment: _"iteration for a large image could be quite slow"_ As a `Vec<u8>` cannot be reinterpreted as a `Vec<(u8, u8, u8)>`, an iteration is needed for the copy. In any case, this is likely an overestimation of the cost of such a copy. Try it out in your use case and identify whether the performance of this operation is _really_ a problem there. Only then should you look for alternatives.

Comment: @E_net4 Even if you need a copy, it can be just a memcpy. It is likely not with the current code. And `Vec<u8>` can be interpreted as `Vec<(u8, u8, u8)>` (not exactly but similar).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I believe that you are assuming that the ABI of `(u8, u8, u8)` is equivalent to three adjacent `u8`s, which is not. The layout of values in a tuple are unspecified. Maybe a very special kind of SIMD instruction could work with this, but it sounds unlikely.

Comment: @E_net4 No, I do not. This is why I said it is possible only similarly. You can define a `#[repr(C)]` tuple struct.

Comment: Is a tuple is really necessary, or would something with a more predictable layout such as `[u8; 3]` suffice? This should preferably be clarified before reopening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itertools has a [`tuples()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuples) adapter which groups consecutive items by tuples.

Alternatively and a bit more limited, the standard library has [`slice::chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks) and [`slice::chunks_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_exact). That needs a slice input (or something which derefs to a slice, like a vec) and you lose the type-safety aspects (as they return slices, possibly smaller than specified for `chunks`) but they don't require a dependency.

Comment: This will not be faster, which is OP's requirement.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman One should not make any performance claims without testing. The example in the question does not even work at all, so we don't even have a reasonable baseline.